# "Shell Command: Install" command missing from Command Palette - VS code - ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, path, visual-studio-code

I cannot find the command to install shell commands to the path on the Command Palette in VS code for Ubuntu.Is it possible that something went wrong during the installation, or is there a solution that I am missing?

When I type in "Shell", my options are "Terminal: Allow Workspace Shell Configuration" and "Python: Run Selection/Line in Django Shell". There is nothing listed to Install a Shell command.

Comment: I used the search function to try to find an answer for quite a while before asking this. I believe is a reasonable question in that I am unable to use an essential feature of the software

Comment: I have this problem currently. IMHO, you shouldn't have accepted the answer that  you did, unless it actually solved your problem (and it doesn't sound like it did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With latest version of vscode you should be able to `ctrl + shift + p` or `cmd + shift + p` (or whatever the hotkey is on ubuntu) and search for shell and then get what you see in the image.

[image]

It is said on the Vscode documentation: "*Note: Users on macOS must first run a command (Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH)*", so maybe the command is only available when running vscode from mac, and not ubuntu (and windows for that matter)? I don't know

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be correct. I tried it on a Mac and "Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH"  was listed

Comment: If the answer was correct can you mark it as so? :-)